# Only last update to messageProperty in a Task is received by the change listener of a bound property

Tags: javafx

In my JavaFX-11 fxml application, I have a simple test Task:

```
public class TestTask extends Task<Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
         updateMessage("TestTask message before sleep 1");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
         updateMessage("TestTask message after  sleep 1");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
         updateMessage("TestTask message after sleep 2");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
         updateMessage("TestTask message after sleep 3");
        return null;
    }
}
```

In the fxml controller class, I have bound a property to the Task message property, and a change listener that I want to use to write the messages in a log window:

```
TestTask testTask = new TestTask();
SimpleStringProperty taskMessage = new SimpleStringProperty();
taskMessage.bind(testTask.messageProperty());
taskMessage.addListener(cl -> {
   System.out.println("taskMessage change listener invoked, new value = " + taskMessage.getValue());
   msgList.add(taskMessage.getValue());
});
```

I start the thread like this:

```
Thread computationThread = new Thread(testTask);
computationThread.setDaemon(true);
computationThread.start();
```

The console shows the following messages:

```
taskMessage change listener invoked, new value = 
taskMessage change listener invoked, new value = TestTask message after sleep 3
```

I know that "intermediate message values may be coalesced to save on event notifications", but here we are talking about only 4 messages, separated by 1 second. They can hardly swamp the event queue, so I don't understand why the bound property is only updated twice: once with an empty message and a second time with the last message.

Comment: [mcve] please .. your setup looks a bit fishy: bind happens via InvalidationListener and your listener to the bound property is also an invalidationListener - so the reason might be that you are seeing only the invalidation ... except .. getValue forces the validation again ..

Comment: I would definitely try adding a `ChangeListener` instead of an `InvalidationListener`.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions. I had copied and pasted the code from a JavaFX application I had developed with JavaFX 8 and Eclipse, where the change listener seemed to be working fine, but I hadn't realized it was an invalidation listener. When I tried to re-write the addListener part without using a lambda expression, I have noticed the mistake. In the process I have also learned that in the controller class I can't have code that wait for a Task to finish, because that would block the JavaFX Application thread and prevent any updateMessage to be processed.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `ChangeListener` is the correct way of doing it.
When I started writing the lambda expression, the IDE suggested a list of applicable listeners and I had accidentally accepted the suggestion of an `InvalidationListener`.